# Spring: Update DB-table entry when web-application is started and stopped

Tags: java, spring

I have to update a table entry when application is started and stopped.
I have a service which has the calls to the DAO method but when this DAO method is called the `SessionFactory` which is autowired is null.

I have used 2 methods:

1. @PostConstruct, @PreDestroy
2. ApplicationListener onApplicationEvent()

In both the cases I am getting the `SessionFactory` as null in the DAO class. I am using Setter-Injection in the DAO class for injecting the `SessionFactory`.

Environment: JDBC-Datasource, Hibernate 3.4, Spring 3.1.2, Weblogic 10.3

It would be great if you could point me in the right direction.

Update:
Thanks for all your comments I got it resolved.Our app is a EAR and my DAO bean config was in a different WAR's applicationContext.xml. I moved the DAO bean config to my shared configuration (appConfig.xml) and it worked like charm. I used @PostConstruct and @PreDestroy

Comment: Show us your context and show us the classes involved (ie. the class with a `SessionFactory` injected).

Comment: You might want to look into [`SmartLifeCycle`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/SmartLifecycle.html)

Comment: Post the code where you are injecting the session factory and post the xml file of spring configuration.

Comment: `@PostConstruct` executes after bean has been initialized, so `sessionFactory` can not be null, if you configured the beans properly.

Comment: Do you have the same problems when using [`InitializingBean.afterPropertiesSet()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html#afterPropertiesSet--) as entry point?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `SmartLifecycle` interface and then configuring it as a bean:

```
<bean class="com.my.package.MySmartlifecycle">
```

And your implementation:

```
public class MySmartLifecycle implements SmartLifecycle{
    //autowire anything you need from context
    @Override
    public void start() {
        //do stuff on startup here
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        //do stuff on shutdown here
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRunning() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPhase() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAutoStartup() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void stop(Runnable callback) {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute method after the context is initialized, you have to use ContextRefreshedEvent. In case of context destroying you should use ContextStoppedEvent, but you also have to remebmer that there is no guarantee that this event will be posted.

```
@Component
public class SpringStartedListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
    // do something
  }
}

@Component
public class SpringClosedListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextStoppedEvent> {

  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(ContextStoppedEvent event) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

If you need some more details please refer to http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/event_handling_in_spring.htm